# variable across different jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp

I have a hashtable which i would be accessing from many jsp pages of my application. I dont understand where to declare hashtable.plz help

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it in application scope which will make it available to all jsp pages (plus the rest of your application).

```
<jsp:useBean id="myHashtable" class="java.util.Hashtable" scope="application" />
```

By including the above line in your jsp pages, they will all share the same instance (per server, different servers will have different instances). If the Hashtable doesn't exist when the jsp page is loaded, the container will create it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it would be an application object:

```
application.setAttribute( "myApplicationHashTable", myHashTable );
```

http://www.gulland.com/courses/JavaServerPages/jsp_objects3.jsp